# Is there a way to change the exception message in oracle?

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have a PHP application on top of an Oracle DB. In the database, there are some constraints defined. When they get violated, I get a plain `constraint violated` message. I would like to have some custom message shown to the user.

Is there a way to define in the definition of the constraint a custom error message ? Or how would you suggest me to approach this issue ?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't want to. The question needs to remain generic. Although, I can give an example. Let's say I want to insert a new entry in my Student table. For several columns I have constraints defined, like name has to be not null, surname has to be not null, age must be positive, and so on. When I insert my new student, one of the constraints may get violated and I get an error message that is not very user friendly. This is why I would like to define an error message within each constraint that I would receive when it gets violated. To be able to show it to the user such that he understands it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068792/is-there-way-to-give-user-friendly-error-message-on-constraint-violation

Answer (score 0):

Catch the exception and inform the user however you feel is appropriate.

[php: catch exception and continue execution, is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132759/php-catch-exception-and-continue-execution-is-it-possible)

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself why your invalid data is reaching your database?

You should implement strong validation on your inputs to prevent this happening as the constraints are only there as a last resort, not a front line for validating data.

Create validation routines that trap and report back (with a useful message) invalid data only sending valid data to be inserted into your database.

This could be done using PL/SQL stored procedures/packages/functions, a good article on using them for CRUD operations is here: 
http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Oracle/Developing-Simple-PL-SQL-Stored-Procedures-for-CRUD-Operations/

Or you could potentially use database triggers for this purpose, though "BEFORE" operation triggers are not as efficient as bulk processing collection data in a PL/SQL validation package.

Hope this helps...